# Magento 2.2.5 How to display item prices out of stock

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.2

Even if Magento 2.2.5 Configrable Product is out of stock, I want to display the item price.

How can I see the price?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display out of stock Configurable Product price then need to override `Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox.php` file and change the code in `protected function _toHtml()` for display out of stock Configurable Product price.

**Follow below file path.**

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/OutofstockProductPrice/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_OutofstockProductPrice',
    __DIR__
);
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/OutofstockProductPrice/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_OutofstockProductPrice" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/OutofstockProductPrice/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox"
        type="Vendor\OutofstockProductPrice\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox"
        type="Vendor\OutofstockProductPrice\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
</config>
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/OutofstockProductPrice/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\OutofstockProductPrice\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Msrp\Pricing\Price\MsrpPrice;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox as BasePriceBox;

class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $result = parent::_toHtml();
        if(!$result) {
            $result = BasePriceBox::_toHtml();
            try {
                /** @var MsrpPrice $msrpPriceType */
                $msrpPriceType = $this->getSaleableItem()->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('msrp_price');
            } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                $this->_logger->critical($e);
                return $this->wrapResult($result);
            }
            //Renders MSRP in case it is enabled
            $product = $this->getSaleableItem();
            if ($msrpPriceType->canApplyMsrp($product) && $msrpPriceType->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product)) {
                /** @var BasePriceBox $msrpBlock */
                $msrpBlock = $this->rendererPool->createPriceRender(
                    MsrpPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                    $this->getSaleableItem(),
                    [
                        'real_price_html' => $result,
                        'zone' => $this->getZone(),
                    ]
                );
                $result = $msrpBlock->toHtml();
            }
            return $this->wrapResult($result);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Run below command:**

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: The price is displayed. But it is unnatural that the price becomes zero.